# There is a downside to overwrite an object instead of update appengine storage?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

i have a class like:

```
class myclass{
    Long id;
    String a;
    Text b;
}
```

in the examples in the documentation for appengine, to update an object, we must recover it from the DataStore, modify it and then close the PersistenceManager.
what if i overwrite it without recover it from the DataStore?
i have that object cached, so i have your id and others properties

Comment: Sounds prone to race conditions for one.

Comment: @Thomas: On App Engine, load-modify-store does not protect against race conditions due to concurrent updates, either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can overwrite it directly without first loading the previous values. (Blind Update)

However, this does not work if you need to know these old values, for example in a partial update of only certain fields.

Comment: so the text properties is deleted or updated with blind update?

Comment: When you store the object, all its properties are reset to whatever the Java object has. An old value will not be preserved. There is no partial update (like you could do in SQL).